# Parsing HTML in using Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing

I am looking for a way to parse html in `Objective-C` to display a `UITableView`. I can't find any tutorials on this topic and its essential for the app.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post was a while ago but in case anyone else is looking for help check out the tutorial on the Raywenderlich website. Worked for me.

[link to raywenderlich html parsing tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

u can get the sample code of html parsing here